# How do I access username on the server side using Windows authentication on a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, windows-authentication

I have Silverlight application with a WCF service using Windows Authentication.
My users get authenticated correctly. And I can access their username and roles on client side.
But how do I do the same thing on server side?
I've tried this

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity
```

and

```
IIdentity caller = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity;
```

It is what I found as an answer on a similar question here on stackoverflow but it doesn't compile.
I get a 'ServiceSecurityContext does not contain definition for Current' exception.

So how do I get the user on server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
HttpContext.Current.User;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This will only work if the service has been set to ASP.NET compatibility mode.

Comment: really? doesn't this get username from request header?

Comment: According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx  "HttpContext: Current is always null when accessed from within a WCF service. Use RequestContext instead." ... unless your service is decorated with ASP.NET Compatability

Comment: From same article: 

WCF applications that require functionality traditionally provided by the HTTP pipeline should consider using the WCF equivalents, which are host and transport independent:

    OperationContext instead of HttpContext.

Comment: I tried it and it works. My wcfService is created in the same project as silverlight web host, so I asume it is set to ASP.NET compatibility mode automatically

Answer (score 3):

```
public static string GetUserIdentity()
{
   return OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name;
}
```

OperationContext is in the System.ServiceModel namespace.